# SQL Group by on multiple conditions on same table

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot, case

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BFaX.png)I am trying to write an SQL query to get below output.

table has below data:

```
   ID   GENDER 
    10  M 
    10  F 
    10  F 
    20  F 
    20  M
```

Output:

```
    ID  Male    Female 
    10   1       2 
    20   1       1
```

do i need to use case with group by. Can someone help here.

Comment: Yes, GROUP BY with CASE expresssions is the standard procedure here.

Comment: add database tag too pls if you want better guidance

Comment: You can also check out ["dynamic-pivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot?tab=Frequent) tag 
 tag depending on your DBMS brand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple group

```
select id,sum(case when GENDER = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as Male,
          sum(case when GENDER = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as FeMale
       from tablename
group by id
```